# Finder won't remember the view settings for smb folders

Tags: finder, smb, nas

macOS 13.1 (22C65)

My default settings for all Finder folders **that I already set**

- list view
- **group by kind**
- sort by name

I have the Synology NAS, and it mounted to Finder via SMB like smb://synologynas

Here's the problem

1. Go to random Synology folder
2. See grouping **NONE** (it's strange. I already set group by kind for everything)
3. Change grouping **by KIND**
4. Close this folder
5. Go to the folder again
6. See grouping **NONE**

Finder just don't want to remember smb folders view settings?
How to fix that?

Comment: See [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208209) at Apple Support for a clue.